# Excel - When enter a value: error instead of locked cell

Tags: excel, vba, locking

When you enter a value the cell should be locked. Just the yellow cells should be able to lock. But always when I enter something in the cell i get this error code:

[image: error]

The error in the code:
[image: code]

Full code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet1.Unprotect "1234"

If VBA.IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then

    Target.Locked = False

Else

    Target.Locked = True

End If

Sheet1.Protect "1234"

End Sub
```

table:

[image: table]

Comment: To fix your immediate error, you just need to define your sheet (e.g. Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "1234"). However, when your sheet is locked, you won't be able to enter anything, regardless of if your code is trying to unlock it right after.

Comment: How should the code look like?
I tried to define the Sheet like that:
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "1234"

Comment: Also after I enter something in an empty cell, this error appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason you are getting the error is you do not have a sheet called Sheet1.  You may have renamed or deleted the first sheet at some point.

To call a Worksheet dynamically from a range you can use `Range.Worksheet`.  This will give you the worksheet of the range you are using.

Here is a way to use it in your scenario:

First it requires a bit of Prep

1. Select All cells in worksheet
2. Right Click --> Format Cells
3. Protection Tab
4. Uncheck Locked.  (This means no cell on the sheet is locked)

When a cell is edited if it was yellow and has a value in it, it will locked. Then all the cells on that worksheet will be locked if they were set to be locked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Only deal with one Cell.
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        'Target background is Yellow (You may have to modify the code to the RGB value of your yellow) and value is Empty
        If Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102) And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.Worksheet.Unprotect "1234"
            Target.Locked = True
            Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="1234", Contents:=True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```